# Quantifiers solution writing

Tags: quantifiers

For a problem such as:$$\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\exists j\in \mathbb{Z},k=j+1.$$I can immediately see that this is false as it does not hold for all $k$, for instance when $j=-10$, $k$ becomes negative and that is not a natural number. However how do I write like a proper explanation on my answers if this was to be answered in an exam?

Comment: You are misreading the claim.  In English, it says "For every natural number $k$ we can find an integer $j$ such that $k=j+1$".  Indeed, just take $j=k-1$.  The example you give would be a counterexample for the claim $\forall j\in \mathbb Z,\,\exists k\in \mathbb N$ such that $k=j+1$" but that's a very different claim.

Comment: As to the logic, a single counterexample suffices to disprove a claim.  So, for example, your example instantly disproves the claim I wrote in my prior comment.  As mentioned, though, it does not disprove the claim you wrote.

Comment: So technically speaking, the above statement is true because for every $k$, we can find a $j$ such that the statement holds true. But how do we show that mathematically?

Comment: Not "technically speaking" .  It's just plain true.  To prove it, take $j=k-1$.  I don't know how you have defined the integers, but I assume you have shown (or assumed) that the integers are closed under subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume $k \in \mathbb{N}$. We know that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, k - 1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, so:

Take $j = k - 1$

$$
k = j + 1 \iff k = (k-1) + 1 \iff k = k - 1 + 1 \iff k = k
$$

---

By induction (seems overkill though), take $j = k - 1 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Base case, $k=0$:

$$
0 = (0 - 1) + 1 \iff 0 = 0
$$

Inductive step:

Assuming $k = n$, and that $n = (n - 1) + 1$ holds, we want to check if $n + 1 = ((n+1) -1) + 1$ holds

$$
n + 1 = ((n+1) -1) + 1 \iff n + 1 = (n + 1 -1) + 1 \iff n + 1 = n + 1
$$

Since both the base case and the inductive step are true, then the original statement holds for every natural number $k$.